# Symfony Cron run Action

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I have Symfony 2.6.11 I use cron and I need run some script

```
$all_developer = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')->findAll();
foreach ($all_developer as $session_developer) {
    //some logic
}
```

I know how to run app/console 'somne comand' but if I need run some code I don't know how this code run.
Help how add this code in app/console or any solved ??

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see a command example ([source](https://codedump.io/share/3OiSO9vDRJKK)) over here:

```
<?php

namespace Application\CommandBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * Class testCommand
 * @package Application\CommandBundle\Command
 */
class TestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    /**
     * Configuration of the command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('command:do:something')
            ->setDescription('This command does something');
    }

    protected function initialize(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface  $input  An InputInterface instance
     * @param OutputInterface $output An OutputInterface instance
     *
     * @return null|int null or 0 if everything went fine, or an error code
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $inputInterface, OutputInterface $outputInterface)
    {
        $outputInterface->writeln(
            'This command does something <info>' . $inputInterface->getOption('env') . '</info> environment'
        );

        $this->getContainer()->get('application_command.test')->doSomething();

        $outputInterface->writeln('Done');
    }

}
```

In that example the code gets the application_command.test service and will run the `doSomething()` method of that service/class:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('application_command.test')->doSomething();
```